# If $G$ is solvable, is it true that for any $m,n\in\operatorname{cd}(G)$, there exists a prime $p$ such that $p\mid m,n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $\operatorname{cd}(G)$ be the set of degrees of irreducible characters of $G$. It is known that if for any $m,n \in \operatorname{cd}(G) \setminus \{1\}$, there exists a prime $p$ such that $p \mid m,n$, then $G$ is solvable. Does the converse hold? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a reference to the result? I don't think I have seen it before.

Comment: Here. http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2007-135-03/S0002-9939-06-08651-5/

Comment: Thank you. I will have to add that one to my todo list.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, take for example $S_4$, which has character degrees $1,2,$ and $3$.